# vb.net mdi parent hides when another form opens

Tags: vb.net

I have a program written in vb.net. It has a mdi parent form as the main form and several child forms. I also have dozens of forms that are not child forms and when I use showdialog() the mainform(MDI parent) hides behind other open applications until the the new form(not child form) finishes opening. I tried showdialog(me) and it doesn't work. I can't use just form.show(me). I searched for hours and can't find a fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

form2.TopMost = True 
form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal 
form2.ShowDialog(Me) 
this code is called from toolstripmenu from the mainform

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. And please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: Set `form2.TopMost = False` and `form2.ShowDialog(Me)`, so if you click outside the main MDI form bringing another application to front,  the Dialog will follow the MDI form.

Comment: Tried that and when i click to open form2 it puts the mainform(parent) form behind other programs that are open until the form2 is finished loading then the mainform comes to the front.